# Converting from hexadecimal to binary

Tags: assembly, mips

If I was given that `$a0 = "ABcd1234"` how would I go about making

```
$v0 = 1010 1011 1100 1101 0001 0010 0011 0100
```

I have written a program already that checks that the $a0 regsiter has valid characters, but I am stumped trying to convert it to binary. Would I just create two arrays, one for the hex values and then one that contains the corresponding binary number for each one? If I did that, how would I go about converting them and then storing such a large value into $v0

Comment: Is $a0 is a string representation of a hexadecimal number?

Comment: .asciiz "ABcd1234" is how I have the code in the .data section

Answer (score 0):

As you have broken the binary up it's obvious that you know that each hex digit is 4 bits. As such, just write code that turns a single digit into 4 bits, and shift them into the target register one after another. You can combine that into the checking code, such as:

```
out=0
foreach(x in string)
{
    if (x < '0') goto invalid;
    if (x < '9' + 1) { value = x - '0'; goto valid; }
    if (x < 'A') goto invalid;
    if (x < 'F' + 1) { value = x - 'A' + 10; goto valid; }
    if (x < 'a') goto invalid;
    if (x < 'f' + 1) { value = x - 'a' + 10; goto valid; }
    goto invalid;

valid:
    out = (out << 4) | value;
}
```

See the [code in operation](http://ideone.com/qAUuZv).

Comment: So how would I go about turning a single digit into 4 bits though?

Comment: I have shown that, which part is unclear? `value` is the 4 bit value :) It's just a subtraction of a constant.

Comment: out = (out << 4) | value     is confusing me a little. I have a number, lets say A = 41, how do I convert from 41 to 1010

Comment: That part only deals with shifting in the 4 bit values. It already uses the converted `value` from earlier. Since you have `A` you take the 4th `if` that does `x - 'A' + 10` and thus `41 - 41 + 10` which is obviously `10` and that is `1010` in binary (which the computer uses).

Comment: Okay I will try to see if that fits what I need. Thanks